# How to formulate the position of each number in a magic square?

Tags: c++

How did this code formulate the position of each numbers? I'm kinda dumb at math and I can't contact the one who made this code. so can anyone enlighten me with this? especially on the test positions part.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
   int magicsq[3][3];
   int i, j, x;

   int row = 0;              // start position of row
   int col = 3 / 2;          // and column
 
   for ( i = 0; i < 3 ; i++ )
   {
      for ( j = 0 ; j < 3; j++ ) magicsq[i][j] = 0;              //initialize to 0 your matrix
   }
 
   magicsq[row][col] = 1;         //position to start the counting
 
   for ( x = 2; x <= 3 * 3; x++ )
   {
      int r = row - 1, c = col - 1;    // test positions
      if (r < 0) r += 3;
      if (c < 0) c += 3;
      if ( magicsq[r][c]>0)
      {
         row++;
         if ( row >= 3 ) row -= 3;
      }
      else
      {
         row = r;
         col = c;
      }
      magicsq[row][col] = x;
   }
 
   for ( i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
   {
      for ( j = 0; j < 3; j++ ) cout << magicsq[i][j] << " ";
      cout<<endl;
   }
}
```

Comment: Try printing the contents of `row` and `col` at every iteration of the second for loop to see the pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This program is about creating a magic square according to the "de la Loubère" method. There is a very good explanation on Wikipedia [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_square#Special_methods_of_construction). You should read that. It has even animated graphics. Very nice.

The code that you found, is not nice. It is imply ugly and you should not waste your time in understanding it.

The mechanism tocreate a magix square is totally simple. Start at the top middle and then always go up and right (take boundaries into account). If the next place is already occupied, then go one down.

The link shows a step by step example.

This should answer your question.

Additionally, I will show you a different solution, with a better style and using C++ elements. (not C-Style arrays and stuff)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <array>

// The maximumn dimension of the magic square
constexpr size_t MaxDimension{ 21u };

// Some abbreviations for less typing work. Square will be implemented as a 2 dimensional std::array
using Square = std::array< std::array <int, MaxDimension>, MaxDimension>;

// Create a magic square following the method of "De-la-Loubère"
void createMagicSquare(Square& square, int sizeOfSquare) {
    
    // Reset all values in the square to 0
    square = {};

    // Starting row and column. Set to upper middle cell
    int row{}; int column{ sizeOfSquare / 2};

    // This will wrap a position if it leaves the boundary of the square
    auto wrap = [&sizeOfSquare](const int position) { return (position + sizeOfSquare) % sizeOfSquare; };

    // Now build the magic square and fill it with all numbers
    for (int runningNumber{ 1 }; runningNumber <= (sizeOfSquare * sizeOfSquare); ++runningNumber) {

        // Write number into cell at current position
        square[row][column] = runningNumber;

        // If the upper right cell is occupied
        if (square[wrap(row-1)][wrap(column+1)] != 0) {

            // Then just go one rowe down
            row = wrap(row + 1);
        } 
        else {
            // Next position will be upper right
            row = wrap(row - 1);
            column = wrap(column + 1);
        }
    }
}
// Output of the magic square
void display(Square& square, int sizeOfSquare)
{
    constexpr int Width = 4;
    std::cout << "\nThe Magic square is: \n\n";

    for (int row = 0; row < sizeOfSquare; ++row) {
        for (int column = 0; column < sizeOfSquare; ++column)
            std::cout << std::setw(Width) << square[row][column];
        std::cout << "\n\n";
    }
}

int main()
{
    // Give instruction what to do
    std::cout << "Enter The Size of the Magic Square (odd number (<=21): ";

    // Read user inpuit and make sure that it is a correct value
    if (int sizeOfSquare{}; (std::cin >> sizeOfSquare) and (sizeOfSquare <= MaxDimension) and (sizeOfSquare%2)) {

        // Define the empty square
        Square square{};

        // Fill it with magic numbers
        createMagicSquare(square, sizeOfSquare);

        // Show result
        display(square, sizeOfSquare);
    }
    else std::cerr << "\nError: Wrong Input\n";
}
```